Why events cannot be used inside of a WebExtension
PreReq.:

Firefox (latest)
WebExtension V2 / V3 (the version doesn't matter)


I have several content scripts in a WebExtension, all organized in classes. Assume I have two classes connected by the event executed.
FooBar.js
class FooBar extends EventTarget
{
    execute()
    {
        this.dispatchEvent(
            new Event( 'executed' )
        );
    }
}

BarFoo.js
class BarFoo
{
    #message = 'fooBar executed';

    execute()
    {
        const fooBar = new FooBar();
        fooBar.addEventListener( 'executed', this.#fooBar_executed );
        fooBar.execute();
    }

    #fooBar_executed = ( event ) =>
    {
        console.log( this.#message );
    }
}

main.js
( new BarFoo() )
    .execute();

manifest.json
{
    ...,
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "https://example.com/*"
            ],
            "js": [
                "FooBar.js",
                "BarFoo.js",
                "main.js"
            ]
        }
    }
}

The event will be dispatched as expected. But the event handler won't be executed. There is no exception, no error, no nothing. But why?

See the update. I tried manifest V3 with the same result.

Yep, seeing the same here in Firefox, while Chrome is ok, so apparently it's a bug in Firefox. Write your own event emitter or use a library, I guess?

Will see if they make attempts to solve the issue ... https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1894258

Things going slow but they're going over at BugZillas' ... https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1894258
This is my current workaround in my realworld base class.
'use strict';

class BaseClass
{
    #eventHandlers = {};

    addEventListener( eventType, eventHandler )
    {
        if ( undefined === this.#eventHandlers[ eventType ] )
        {
            this.#eventHandlers[ eventType ] = [
                eventHandler
            ];

            return;
        }

        this.#eventHandlers[ eventType ]
            .push( eventHandler );
    }

    async dispatchEvent( event )
    {
        if ( undefined !== this.#eventHandlers[ event.type ] )
        {
            this.#eventHandlers[ event.type ]
                .forEach(
                    async ( eventHandler ) =>
                    {
                        eventHandler( event );
                    }
                );
        }
    }
}

So it's easy in the future to remove those event handling implementation and derive the base class from EventTarget without changing any dependent class.
